# Identityserver JWKS endpoint generates Nullreference

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, identity

When accessing https://example.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks in order to debug my Identityserver issues (The key {xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} was not found in the key ring), the JWKS endpoint fails and returns the following;

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Object.GetType()
   at Duende.IdentityServer.ResponseHandling.DiscoveryResponseGenerator.CreateJwkDocumentAsync() in /_/src/IdentityServer/ResponseHandling/Default/DiscoveryResponseGenerator.cs:line 440
   at Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint.ProcessAsync(HttpContext context) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Endpoints/DiscoveryKeyEndpoint.cs:line 54
   at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events, IIssuerNameService issuerNameService, IBackChannelLogoutService backChannelLogoutService) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/IdentityServerMiddleware.cs:line 103
   at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events, IIssuerNameService issuerNameService, IBackChannelLogoutService backChannelLogoutService) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/IdentityServerMiddleware.cs:line 103
   at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.MutualTlsEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/MutualTlsEndpointMiddleware.cs:line 95
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.DynamicProviders.DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/DynamicProviders/DynamicSchemes/DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.cs:line 48
   at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/BaseUrlMiddleware.cs:line 32
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Any thoughts on what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

You should see a key in the JWKS endpoint when you use AddDeveloperSigningCredential(). If not, then you have some other issues.

As I mentioned earlier, there is also a built-in Key management system in IdentityServer, and it creates its keys in the \Keys folder, as the image below shows:

[image]

If you don't use the key manager, then you should disable it using:

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.KeyManagement.Enabled = false;
    ...
});
```

Comment: I do see a key when doing this locally, BUT when having deployed into the Linux environment I get the JWKS endpoint error. And in Linux I cannot use the AddDeveloperSigningCredential as it is not viable for production as I understand it. Also, I tried applying your options.keymanagement = false, yet the same issue occurs unfortunately...

Comment: You can add AddDeveloperSigningCredential  in production for testing, but not recommended for real production usage, as you will get a new key each time you redeploy (making existing keys invalid). So, I recommend starting witn AddDeveloperSigningCredential   and make sure that works.

Comment: same issue occurs when deploying with AddDeveloperSigningCredential. The JWKS endpoint fails with the exact same error message.

Comment: I would look at the startup log of IdentityServer in production, it is usually very verbose and good.

Comment: AddDeveloperSigningCredential usually writes a file to the local filesystem, does your app have the rights to write to the disk? also any exceptions in your logs?